# LibreOffice Impress textbox - decrease the distance of each movement

Tags: libreoffice

Sometimes I only need a slight movement, but it actually moves way over what I needed, making aligning screen items very hard. Often, I had to do tricks to make the alignment look better, for example, by using an empty line of smaller font above the actual content to push it down just a little.

Is there a way to decrease how much the textbox moves per "drag"?

Please see the screenshot, by dragging the textbox up, it goes quite a wide distance.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since this tool suite is now available for many platforms besides Linux, it would seem to be off-topic on this site. Did you try asking on a LibreOffice user's/developer's forum?

Comment: @AdminBee If you feel it should be removed please do so. I'll find another forum. Thanks.